# Order by many columns with join and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `Companies` and `Contact` with relation one to many, and  I want to 
select company name and contact counts and next order by them, but it dosen't work.

```
SELECT comp.Name , count(cc.Id) CCount 
FROM Contacts cc JOIN Companies comp ON comp.Id = cc.Company_id
GROUP BY comp.Name 
ORDER BY CCount desc, comp.Name desc
```

Now I get result sorted by contact count but not by Name

```
SELECT comp.Name , count(cc.Id) CCount 
FROM Contacts cc JOIN Companies comp ON comp.Id = cc.Company_id
GROUP BY comp.Name 
ORDER BY comp.Name desc, CCount desc
```

And now I get results sorted by name but not by count

Comment: Could you show us some actual results, and what you were instead expecting?

Comment: The order by works just fine. This question seems odd

Comment: [t-clausen.dk] It semms that you have right, question was liitle odd ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always post DDL and INSERT statements.  Here's what I'd expect.

```
create table companies (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table contacts (
  id integer primary key,
  company_id integer references companies (id)
);

insert into companies values (1, 'First');
insert into companies values (2, 'Second');
insert into companies values (3, 'Third');

-- Companies 'First' and 'Third' both have 3 contacts.
insert into contacts values (100,1);
insert into contacts values (101,1);
insert into contacts values (102,1);
insert into contacts values (201,2);
insert into contacts values (301,3);
insert into contacts values (302,3);
insert into contacts values (303,3);
```

Your first query.

```
SELECT comp.Name , count(cc.Id) CCount 
FROM Contacts cc JOIN Companies comp ON comp.Id = cc.Company_id
GROUP BY comp.Name 
ORDER BY CCount desc, comp.Name desc

name    ccount
--
Third   3
First   3
Second  1
```

`ORDER BY CCount desc` will put the larger numbers at the top. Within each group of identical ccounts, the names will be sorted descending. "Second" is in the last row, because its ccount is 1.

Your second query.

```
SELECT comp.Name , count(cc.Id) CCount 
FROM Contacts cc JOIN Companies comp ON comp.Id = cc.Company_id
GROUP BY comp.Name 
ORDER BY comp.Name desc, CCount desc

name    ccount
--
Third   3
Second  1
First   3
```

`ORDER BY comp.Name desc` will sort descending by company name. Within each group of identical company names, ccounts would be sorted descending. Since *there can't be any groups of identical company names* (Why?), the sort on ccount doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Big thanks for explain, I was going with my mind in strange driaction.

Answer (score 2):

The ORDER BY clause in SQL can sort on multiple columns, it sorts by the fields as they are listed in order, i.e. first it sorts by the first field, and then where the fields value is repeated it sorts by the second field.

---

ORDER BY Name DESC, Count DESC

```
Smith    9
Smith    5
Smith    2
Jones    9
Doe      9
```

The first three rows have a repeated name so they are sorted by count

---

ORDER BY Count DESC, Name DESC

```
Smith    9
Jones    9
Doe      9
Smith    5
Smith    2
```

The first three rows have a repeated count so they are sorted by name

---

If neither of these is what you want, Edit your question add a sample list of records in the order you are looking for.